# Python: Error while connecting to SQL Server (ODBC 17)

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

Getting below error while executing SQL statement using pd.read_sql()

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08001',
> '[08001] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL
> Provider: [error:0A0C0103:SSL routines::internal error] (-1)
> (SQLDriverConnect)')

Python version 3.10.8. Other packages:

- pyodbc==4.0.35
- pandas==1.5.2
- pymysql==1.0.2
- sqlalchemy==1.4.46

I want to execute the above command successfully.

Comment: Could you [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75283975/edit) your question to include the output of `openssl version -a`, and also tell us the version of SQL Server you are connecting to (the full result of `SELECT @@VERSION`)? It sounds like you're trying to connect to an older/unpatched version of SQL Server that only supports TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1 connections while using a newer build of openssl that only supports TLS 1.2 or later.

Answer (score 0):

The error message '**ODBC 17**' distinctively specifies a failure in establishing a connection to a SQL Server database through ODBC driver. This can be caused by;

1. Incorrect connection details such as server name, database name, username, and password.
2. ODBC driver not installed or not properly configured on the machine.

In order to solve this, try and verify the connection details and ensure they are correct or Install or reinstall the ODBC driver and make sure it's properly configured.

If the above doesn't work, kindly check the firewall settings and ensure that the connection is not being blocked.
Hope this helps.